# Mocha equivalent of beforeEach() and afterEach() in Espresso

Tags: android, junit4, ui-automation, android-espresso

My espresso code structure for now is

@Rule

@Test

//Test 1

@Test

//Test 2

Now I want to **clear app data**(among few other operations) before each test execution.

In mocha I was using **beforeEach()** and **afterEach()** for this.

I want to know if Espresso offers similar methods.
I not then how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these annotations:

[@After](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html)

[@Before](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html)

```
@After
public void clear()
{
    //clearData
}
```

Comment: It runs before and after all test cases not each testcase.

Comment: Im sure that @Before executes before each test. BeforeClass executes before all test in suite. http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html